# Applying Posixlt to column with multiple formats

Tags: r

I have a very large dataset that contains a list of different date formats, namely the following:

```
2016-12-07 06:24:49
05/12/2017 08:01
05/12/2018 08
19.02.2018 04:32:35
06-01-2018 00:32:24
```

I am trying to convert them all to posixlt since the entire column is of the character class. I need to keep all the information though.

I tried the following for each one:

```
df.all.copy$Time <- as.POSIXlt(df.all.copy$Time, tz="GMT", format = c("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"), optional = F)
```

This one after applying the following function:

```
df.all.copy$Time <- gsub("/", "-", df.all.copy$Time)
df.all.copy$Time <- gsub(".", "-", df.all.copy$Time)


df.all.copy$Time <- as.POSIXlt(df.all.copy$Time, tz="GMT", format, tryFormats = c("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
                                                                        "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"), optional = F)
```

But it just doesn't work, the above only applies the function to 1/2 of them, leaving the rest as NA.

Any help would be welcome.

Comment: Use `parse_date_time` from `lubridate` which takes multiple formats

Comment: I'll give it a go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the ambiguous day/month for the 2nd and 3rd case is day followed by month, we can use `anytime` to automatically pick up the `format` and convert to DateTime format

```
library(anytime)
anytime(v1)
#[1] "2016-12-07 06:24:49 EST" "2017-05-12 08:01:00 EDT" "2018-05-12 08:00:00 EDT" NA                       
#[5] "2018-06-01 00:00:00 EDT"
```

or specify the format in `parse_date_time`

```
library(lubridate)
parse_date_time(v1,   c("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M",
    "%d/%m/%Y %H", "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S",  "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"))
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c('2016-12-07 06:24:49', '05/12/2017 08:01', '05/12/2018 08', 
      '19.02.2018 04:32:35', '06-01-2018 00:32:24 ')
```